# Is a 60A sub-panel adequate for my workshop/garage?

Tags: electrical-panel

I am upgrading the service to the garage. The old needs total replacement.
In the garage i will be using

- 50A welder
- small compressor
- lighting for 400 square foot garage
- 6 20A receptacles

Would a 60A service be okay?

Total run From main 150A service is 65 feet to  detached garage

Comment: Can you post the I1eff or I1max of the welder, and the HP of your compressor's motor?  Also, do you want HVAC in the garage?

Comment: *Any* chance of ever wanting an electric car hookup?  Or will that never happen?

Comment: Or for that matter, can you post photos of the nameplates from the welder and the compressor motor?

Comment: For the minimal cost increase you'd be wise to go 100A or even 125A.

Comment: I agree with Isherwood, although welders are rarely used at full capacity and even then are not constant loads with that sized welder and a compressor you may end up tripping your main (I use my compressor and the welder at the same time quite often, those loads and some lights a fridge /freezer is really close.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you use 6 AWG copper wire for a 60A run, and 1 AWG Aluminum wire for a 100A run.  Between the two, #1 aluminum is *actually cheaper*, though it requires more expensive conduit if you use conduit.   (using conduit can be a convenience; Rigid conduit only needs to be trenched 6" of cover instead of 24" for buried cable, and Rigid provides a valid ground path, so no need for a ground wire).

The welder could surge 50A, and if the compressor is running at that time, these could peak the circuit past 60A.  This will not immediately trip the breaker, but it could cause minor voltage drop.  **Rather than be in a situation where the circuit is straining at limits during welding, I'd advise erring on "large"**.  It certainly does no harm.

Speaking of "large", we recommend large service panels.  The welder will need 2 spaces, as will any 240V load.  If you put together a respectable 240V workshop, you start blasting through spaces 2 at a time.  Dealing with an over-full panel is much more expensive than just buying a bigger panel in the first place, so we recommend a biggie. And it's perfectly OK for the panel amp rating to be larger than the feed breaker.  Some people think if the breakers are equal size, the one in the shop will trip first - doesn't work that way.

And by the way, you don't need a main breaker in the subpanel.  However you do need a **shutoff switch** if the subpanel is in an outbuilding, and getting a panel with a main breaker is the cheapest way to do that.

Also, because it is an outbuilding, you need two ground rods at least 6' apart.  You can do it with one ground rod if you do an impedance test, but setting two ground rods is easier.  Despite the ground rods, you still need the ground *wire* back to the main panel (or Rigid conduit will substitute). They have different purposes, both important.